# Testing custom hooks with Testing Library/React-Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, testing-library

I have more of a conceptual question regarding testing-library/react-hooks.

I have the following test:

```js
  describe('something else', () => {
    const mock = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: [['NL', 'Netherlands'], ['CU', 'Cuba']], status: 200 });
    axios.get = mock;

    it('calls the api once', async () => {
      const setItemMock = jest.fn();
      const getItemMock = jest.fn();
      global.sessionStorage = jest.fn();
      global.sessionStorage.setItem = setItemMock;
      global.sessionStorage.getItem = getItemMock;

      const { waitFor } = renderHook(() => useCountries());

      await waitFor(() => expect(setItemMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0));
    });
  });
```

Which test the following custom hook:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from '../../shared/utils/axiosDefault';
import { locale } from '../../../config/locales/locale';

type TUseCountriesReturnProps = {
  countries: [string, string][];
  loading: boolean;
  error: string;
}

export default function useCountries(): TUseCountriesReturnProps {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const sessionStorageCountriesKey = `countries-${locale}`;

  useEffect(() => {
    const countriesFromStorage = sessionStorage.getItem(sessionStorageCountriesKey);

    const getCountries = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/v3/countries', {
          params: {
            locale,
          },
        });
        console.log(response);

        if (response.status === 200) {
          setCountries(response.data);
          sessionStorage.setItem(sessionStorageCountriesKey, JSON.stringify(response.data));
        } else {
          console.error(response);
          setError(`Error loading countries, ${response.status}`);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        setError('Failed to load countries');
      }
    };

    if (!countriesFromStorage) {
      getCountries();
    } else {
      setCountries(JSON.parse(countriesFromStorage));
    }

    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  return {
    countries,
    loading,
    error,
  };
}
```

If I change the `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` to `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)`, all of a sudden I get a `Warning: An update to TestComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).` on

```
      29 |         if (response.status === 200) {
    > 30 |           setCountries(response.data);
```

And if I do any number higher than 1, it times out. Even if I extend the timeout time to 30 seconds, it just times out. What is happening here. I just don't understand. And all of that makes me wonder if it is even actually running the test correctly.

Comment: that's weird, different `expect()` should not change how test is executed. If you run test with debugger, is it still a case? did you try upgrading jest? do other tests with `async/await` work fine?

Comment: Yeah, it seems other async/awaits are doing what they should... Jest is running on ^27.3.1. I doubt anything critical changed in the last two subversions, but will give it a go.

What do you mean exactly with running with debugger?

Comment: I mean executing test line-by-line  in your IDE

Comment: Actually, testing some things now on circle CI and the async/await tests that pass locally seem to fail on the CI.

Comment: I've run out of ideas except trying to install different version(s). Have issue with async/await just once and upgrading from 24.x to 25.x solved issue, but still have no idea what rootcause was.

Comment: Thanks anyway =\ There's nothing wrong in the syntax right?

Comment: at least I don't see any issue, maybe missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I figured it out. For some reason the wait for does not work in this situation. I am now doing it as follows and that works in all scenarios:

```js
describe('useCountries', () => {
  describe('when initialising without anything in the sessionStorage', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: [['NL', 'Netherlands'], ['CU', 'Cuba']], status: 200 });
      global.sessionStorage = jest.fn();
      global.sessionStorage.getItem = jest.fn();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    it('calls session storage set item once', async () => {
      const setItemMock = jest.fn();
      global.sessionStorage.setItem = setItemMock;

      const { waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useCountries());
      await waitForNextUpdate();

      expect(setItemMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

So it seems that testing library wants you to just wait for the first update that happens and not until it stops doing things. As soon as it waits for the final results, other updates trigger and those are somehow messing up something internally.. I wish I could be more explicit about why, but as least `waitForNextUpdate` seems to have fixed my issue.